# Avoiding duplicate computation in TF model subparts

Tags: tensorflow

Given the batch of inputs

```
   A   B 
  ________
1 (a1, b1)
2 (a1, b2)
3 (a2, b1)
4 (a2, b2)
```

and a model `(A, B) -> C` composed of three parts:

1. `A -> Ma`
2. `B -> Mb`
3. `(Ma, Mb) -> C`

How can I prevent any duplicated computation (including for backpropagation, ideally)? The first part of the model does the same work for row 1 and 2 of the batch (`a1` is the input to the first part in both cases), while the second part of the model does the same work for row 1 and 3.

Is there a general way to do this, even if the TF model is a black box, and it is unknown how the input gets split internally?

Comment: I'm not following your description of the model.   Could you please give an example (presumably not ideal)?   Thanks

Comment: @MarkLavin The specifics of the model don't matter. Think of a two-tower architecture. `A` could be queries, and `B` products.

Comment: Let me refine your question: The first part of the model does the same work for row 1 and 2 of the batch (a1 is the input to the first part in both cases), while the second part of the model does the same work for row 1 and 3. => `(a1,b1),(a1,b2)` is the input for `A->Ma`, `(a1,b1) ,(a2,b1)` is the input for `B->Mb`. I think you should be clear on terms row/model/input

Comment: @dtlam26 Thanks! Well, technically, `(a1, b1)` and `(a1, b2)` would be inputs for the whole model, but I guess you meant it's the rows for which the part `A -> Ma` does duplicate work, as `a1` is its input in both cases. Being clear for everyone is tricky...

Comment: It is really hard to understand. Is it possible for you to share some flow chart (Your tf graph for example)? That will be easier and also that is how TF works. TF is originally a graph flow with ops. Relying on that we can avoid duplicating processes.